# Displaying Twitter Live search results in two columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I need to display the Twitter live search results(by using the Twitter Search Widget) in two columns as the live search result widget would only display the search results in one column.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't with the twitter search widget, try searching for another plugin which uses the twitter-search-api.

Answer (score 3):

Twitter Widget can be used simply by adding the following style tag you can display it in two columns as below. Also add the div tag twitter_test to the widget as an id and to the html code where it has to be displayed.

```
<style type="text/css">
#twitter_test .twtr-doc, 
#twitter_test .twtr-hd a, 
#twitter_test h3, 
#twitter_test h4{ background:none !important;}
</style>
```